# my question is what means proc near?

Tags: ida, disassembly, debugging

```
sub_123434 proc near 
mov esi, [ebp-1Ch] 
sub_123434 endp
```

What means proc near? Can someone possibly explain also the whole
function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insofar as `proc` and `endp`, start [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01d2az3t.aspx). A good explanation for `near`can be found from [this document](http://spot.pcc.edu/~wlara/asmx86/asmx86_manual_8.pdf), which states as follows:

> Attribute is NEAR if the Procedure is in the same code segment as the
>   calling program; or FAR if in a different code segment.

The meat of the code is this:

```
mov esi,[ebp-1Ch]
```

This bit of code is moving a value from the stack into the `esi` register. Depending on the compiler used and context, you might stand to glean additional information from [register conventions](http://www.swansontec.com/sregisters.html) where a value being moved into the `esi` register is concerned. More specifically, consider the accepted answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856320/purpose-of-esi-edi-registers).

Also, `ebp-` (as opposed to `ebp+`) is a typical sign of arguments that have been passed to a function--of which those values reside on the stack within memory addresses that can be referenced as long as that particular [stack frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057443/explain-the-concept-of-a-stack-frame-in-a-nutshell) exists.

Regarding `[ebp-1Ch]`, that's a pointer. In this case, the `ebp` register contains a memory address (or, more specifically, the value in `ebp` is treated as a reference to a memory address instead of a literal value), and `-1Ch` is an offset from that memory address. The lowercase 'h' is just a pneumonic meaning "hex," and to that end, you might also sometimes see offsets and/or hex-based values referenced with a preceding 0x, like this: `[ebp-0x1C]`. Bearing that in mind, you can really think of that as `[ebp-1C]`.

Do note that `ebp` and `[ebp]` are different things. `[ebp]` means the value inside of `ebp` is treated as a reference to a memory address. Let's assume `ebp` has `0xD34DC0DE` in it. Now consider the following:

```
mov esi,ebp
mov esi,[ebp]
mov esi,[ebp-1C]
```

The results of each of these would be the following:

`mov esi,ebp` // esi now contains the literal value 0xD34DC0DE

`mov esi,[ebp]` // esi now contains whatever is inside the memory address 0xD34DC0DE

`mov esi,[ebp-1C]` // esi now contains whatever is inside the memory address 0xD34DC0C2 (which is 0xD34DC0DE - 1C)

Overall, it looks like that subroutine isn't doing anything but moving data from the stack into a register. As a completely blind assumption, if we assume that each argument passed to its respective function is 4-bytes wide, then `[ebp-1C]` references the 8th argument passed to perhaps a parent routine of this subroutine. In this case, other values of interest could potentially reside in `[ebp]`, `[ebp-04]`, `[ebp-08]`, `[ebp-0C]`, `[ebp-10]`, `[ebp-14]`, and/or `[ebp-18]`.

Ultimately, we're lacking context here to gather what the purpose of this function you've provided is--though, again, a combination of the aforementioned conventions can possibly tell you a lot about what that mov instruction is potentially a part of. Look into [calling conventions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/proc) for additional clarity. You should be able to infer and research the rest based on the information herein.

Comment: @Yoonisj: please post a new question about that and provide relevant code snippets

Comment: call ds: RegOpenKyEx                                                                               call ds: RegEnumKey                                                                                         mov edi,ds:RegCloseKey                                                                                                                                                                                                          what this malware do in this function, if these three function are below each other